# Mongoose aggregate $filter function with date compare lte and gte on nested array object

Tags: mongoose, aggregate-functions, date-comparison

1. I have a schema in Mongo as follows:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5e1d9e1615035fe9867ab058"),
  "farmid": "8f9dbffa-5333-4533-b04c-182e0c147dd8",
  "boxid": "e60bf8df-c75d-11e6-b349-02adcd2575fd",
  "s2": {
    "b2": [
      { "date": ISODate("2019-10-27T05:30:00.000+05:30"), "value": 1761 },
      {
        "date": ISODate("2019-09-22T05:30:00.000+05:30"),
        "value": 6033
      },
      {
        "date": ISODate("2019-06-09T05:30:00.000+05:30"),
        "value": 1581
      },
      {
        "date": ISODate("2019-05-30T05:30:00.000+05:30"),
        "value": 1663
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

2. This is my aggregation code function query with $filter and $gte,$lte operator.

```
let start =  new Date("2019-07-01T05:30:00.000+05:30");
let end =  new Date("2019-12-31T05:30:00.000+05:30");

{
    { 
        $match: { 
            "s2.b2.date":  { $gte: start, $lte: end }
        }
    },
    { 
        $project: {
            "farmid" : 1,
            "boxid":1,
            "s2.b2": {
                $filter: {
                input: "$b2",
                as :"data",
                cond: {
                        $and: [
                             { $gte:["$$data.date",start] } ,
                             { $lte: ["$$data.date",end ] }]
                        }
                }
            },
        }
    },
}
```

3. I am trying to filter the data so I can bring back the data  Which satisfies the query conditions when executing this code I got the output below. In this output, I got the null value in the b2 array.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5e1d9e1415035fe9867600d7",
    "farmid": "7beb32a4-8bf6-49eb-b827-37854a7d0604",
    "boxid": "e60bf85c-c75d-11e6-b349-02adcd2575fd",
    "s2": {
      "b2": null
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e1d9e1415035fe9867600d8",
    "farmid": "dbd06299-12ee-42db-a6e6-9d4e796bc465",
    "boxid": "e60bf85c-c75d-11e6-b349-02adcd2575fd",
    "s2": {
      "b2": null
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e1d9e1415035fe9867600d9",
    "farmid": "b7665ed3-cf10-451d-81b2-d14cec213250",
    "boxid": "e60bf85c-c75d-11e6-b349-02adcd2575fd",
    "s2": {
      "b2": null
    }
  }
]
```

4. Can someone tell the correct solution why this gives me a result like this when data is available on a dataset

Comment: Does the result change if you use `ISODate` instead of `Date` for the `start` and `end` variables?

Comment: Hey Patrick, Doesn't change the result for this case . Fortunately I got where i did mistake , i used direct $b2 as input array which is totally wrong instead that i have to  track array as $s2.b2 .

Comment: So the solution for this case is .    {
         { 
            $match: { 
            "s2.b2.date":  { $gte: start, $lte: end }

          }
        },
          { $project: {
            "farmid" : 1,
            "boxid":1,
            "s2.b2": {
              $filter: {
                input: "$s2.b2",
                as :"data",
                cond: {
                  $and: [
                     { $gte:["$$data.date",start] } ,
                     { $lte: ["$$data.date",end ] }]
                }
              }
            },

          }},

       }